# dblink between RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to create a database link between two RDS instances without any gateway setup?

Comment: Are the two RDS instances in the same VPC? Are they in public subnets or private subnets? Please tell us more about your architecture.

Comment: Yes, they are hosted in same VPC and using public subnets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since your two Amazon RDS database instances are in the same VPC, they can directly communicate with each other.

Make sure that BOTH clusters have Security Groups that allow inbound connections from the other cluster. (There is no concept of both clusters being 'inside' a Security Group. Rather, the Security Groups are applied to each cluster individually.)

When connecting to the other database with `dblink`, use the DNS Name supplied in the Amazon RDS console. This will resolve to a private IP address